Синхронизация в React
Ни как не могу найти информацию, которая мне нужна.
Вопрос - как сделать синхронизацию блока div (если я правильно понимаю реализацию) между пользователями
к примеру, 2 пользователя зашли на одну страницу и могли бы редактировать или видеть контент вместе один и тот же. Например в iframe находится ссылка на видео с YouTube, если первый пользователь запустил или промотал видео, тоже самое отображается в реальном времени у других пользователей. Так же к примеру можно отображать курсоры в этом блоке всех пользователей.
P.S. в блоке div может быть не только iframe

добавить на сервер вебсокеты и отправлять по ним каждое изменение положения курсора и каждое действие
